# how to make framework7 picker modal scrollable

Tags: html-framework-7

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxAtB.png)

As you all can see , I am trying to add a term and conditions into my
Framework7 Picker Modal

but the problem is i cant scroll down in the picker modal
I've been research for few days but I still can't figure out how to do it

Please Help me

Answer (score 1):

You can enable scroll with this css  `style="overflow-y: scroll;`

```
<div class="picker-modal picker-info">
    <div class="toolbar">
      <div class="toolbar-inner">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right"><a href="#" class="close-picker">Done</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="picker-modal-inner">
      <div class="content-block">
        <h4>Info 1</h4>
        <div  style="overflow-y: scroll; height:500px;">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor ...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/kf5jf626/1/